# Uso de " .get(char a) " en C++

Tags: c++

```
void estadisticas ( const string & nombre , bool & ok , Estad & sts )
{
    ifstream fich ;
    fich . open ( nombre . c_str ());
    if ( fich . fail ()) {
        ok = false ;
    } else {
        inic ( sts );
        char c;
        fich . get (c);
        while (! fich . fail ()) {
            procesar (c, sts );
            fich . get (c);
        }
        ok = fich . eof ();
        fich . close ();
    }
}
```

¿Qué es lo que hace el `fich.get(c)` en este codigo

Comment: Y si leemos la documentación? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/

Answer (score 1):

La función recibe una variable tipo `char` por referencia para almacenar en dicha variable el siguiente caracter a leer del fichero.

Un ejemplo tonto que lee un fichero caracter a caracter y los va imprimiendo en la consola:

```
int main()
{
  std::ifstream fichero;
  fichero.open("test.txt");

  while( fichero.good() )
  {
    char c;
    fichero.read(c);
    std::cout << c;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## `istream& istream::get(char& ref_c)`

Es una función perteneciente a los *streams* de C++ la cual se utiliza para obtener el caracter actual dentro del stream y avanzar a la posición siguiente.

Considerese el siguiente archivo de texto *(hola.txt)*:

```
Hola Mundo
```

Al abrir `hola.txt` en un `istream`, la posición empieza en el indice cero del archivo, por lo que al hacer `istream::get(c)` en la variable que contiene el fichero, vas a obtener la letra `H` almacenada en la variable `c` y el archivo ahora apuntará a la siguiente letra *(`o`)*.

Vease el siguiente código;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() 
{
    std::ifstream is("hola.txt");
    while (is.good()) 
    {
        char c = 0;
        is.get(c);
        std::cout << "El caracter actual es: " << c << '\n';
    }
    is.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Obtienes por resultado:

```
El caracter actual es: H
El caracter actual es: o
El caracter actual es: l
El caracter actual es: a
El caracter actual es: 
El caracter actual es: M
El caracter actual es: u
El caracter actual es: n
El caracter actual es: d
El caracter actual es: o
El caracter actual es:
```

Referencia: [C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/).